# How to compile all source files (default make target does not compile all of them)

Tags: android

when I compile android (http://source.android.com/download) it does not compile some source files. For example there is external/bluetooth/bluez/sbc/sbc.c which is not compiled. There are also other such files.

It's possible those files need not to be compiled. Or it might be that I need some special configuration to compile them.

Either way, if it is possible, I'd like to compile them. Is there some way to do it? Maybe some "compile_all" make target?

(I believe the reason why I want to compile all source files is not important)

Answer (score 0):

Make configurations can certainly vary depending on who is doing the build (like different vendors).  You can take a look at people that do custom compilations to get a feel for how they do it, there is some good information regarding Android development (building the OS) on the [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=559) forums although that is primarly regarding phone devices.  But I would take a look at some of the public repositories for people that do Android builds so you can get a feel for the different make configurations, there are a fair amount on [github](http://github.com/), particularly here is Cyanogen's http://github.com/cyanogen/android_build

Comment: How do I use this Cyanogen build to build all files?